# How to sum by grouped columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my input. A dataframe with n columns, and an auxiliary dataframe that assigns each id to a group.

```
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(1,2,3), 
  a2 = c(2,3,4), 
  b1 = c(4,5,6), 
  b2 = c(5,6,7)
)
aux <- data.frame(
  id = c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2"),
  group = c("a", "a", "b", "b")
)
```

What's a generalizable way to get to this output? (summing a1 + a2, and b1 + b2)

```
desired_output <- data.frame(
  a = c(3,5,7),
  b = c(9,11,13)
)
```

I've tried using `dplyr::group_by` and `tidyr::unite`, but I haven't gotten it to work  yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid having to split data frames and pass long lists of data frames through your code, you can just work with the indices:

```
cols <- split(aux$id, aux$group)

data.frame(lapply(cols, function(i) rowSums(df[i])))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `split.default` to split data frame into a list of sub data frames based on the column names *id/pattern*, and then apply `rowSums` to each sub data frame:

```
# create a group variable by columns
g <- aux$group[match(names(df), aux$id)]
g
# [1] a a b b
# Levels: a b

as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, g), rowSums))

#  a  b
#1 3  9
#2 5 11
#3 7 13
```

Comment: Confused as to why you're creating `g` when the OP already has `aux$group`.

Comment: @Frank Just in case the `id` column is not in the same order as the column names of `df`, the match will reorder them. In OP's example, there is probably no need for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty general base R method.

```
# define your groups
myGroups <- c("a", "b")

# get the column positions of your groups, given aux data.frame
myCols <- lapply(unique(aux$group), function(i) which(aux$group == i))

# get the data.frame of the row sums for each colum group
dfNew <- setNames(data.frame(lapply(myGroups, function(i) rowSums(df[i]))), myGroups)
```

This returns

```
dfNew
  a  b
1 3  9
2 5 11
3 7 13
```

Its a bit longer than @psidom's answer, but should be pretty straight forward. In the second line, `lapply` is used on aux to apply `which` to find the column positions for each group element and return the positions in a list. In the third line, `lapply` applies `rowSums` to each group set to and returns a list. This list is converted into a data.frame with `data.frame`and is given column names using `setNames`.

Comment: `grep(i, names(df))` is dangerous. Better to use the mapping given.

Comment: Sorry @PierreLafortune, a bit thick today. What is the danger?

Comment: @lmo Think about an extra group "ba" and you're screwed already. `grep` is not even close to necessary here. In this logic I'd go for `match(i, names(df),0)` instead.

Comment: It narrowly creates a solution that breaks easily in the real-world. It would be okay if there was no other choice and the use-case is strict. But OP provides a mapping to solve ambiguity; your answer ignores it completely.